# Opposite of disappointed

Tags: grammar, negation

The opposite of like is dislike. The opposite of assemble is disassemble. So here, “dis” is a prefix that acts as a negation.

Why is the opposite of “I’m disappointed in you” not “I’m appointed in you”? Is the “dis” actually a prefix or not?

Comment: Why isn't *gusting* the antonym of *disgusting*?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I don’t know. Perhaps the answer to my question will also answer yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Oxford dictionaries, the derivation of *disappoint* is -

> late Middle English (in the sense ‘deprive of a position’).

So I suppose the meaning of *disappointment* has extended over the centuries from the feelings of someone who didn't get a job they had wanted, to cover all kinds of disappointment. People sometimes amuse themselves by thinking of all the English words that exist in the negative form but no longer in the positive, like *unkempt, uncouth* and *disgruntled*.

Oh, and *disgust* comes from the French *dégôut* (distaste).

Comment: Allow me just this one nitpick: ["couth"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couth) _is_ still in the lexicon. It means, approximately, "well-formed".

Comment: Also, words like *disgusting* are called *unpaired words*.

Comment: All straightforward etymology and meaning shift. And *gust* still lingers on in *gustatory*.